# change negative y-axis labels to right side in pstricks

Tags: pstricks, labels, ticks

I have not been able to change the negative y-axis labels to the right side of the y-axis. This is what I need:

[image]

And this is what I currently have compiled with XeLaTex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    %\psgrid[gridcolor=orange!20,subgridcolor=orange!10]
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)[$x$,0] [$y$,90]
    \psline(-1,-1)(0,-1)
    \psline(0,1)(1,1)
    \psdots[dotstyle=Bo](-1,-1)
    \psdots(0,1)
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also I need to eliminate a zero from the origin so that only one remains. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture*}(-3,-3)(3,3)
        %\psgrid[gridcolor=orange!20,subgridcolor=orange!10]
        \psaxes[showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,0)(2.5,2.5)[$x$,0] [$y$,90]
        \psaxes[xAxis=false,ylabelPos=right,showorigin=false](0,0)(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,0)
        \rput[t](-0.15,\dimexpr-\pslabelsep-2pt){\pshlabel{0\strut}}%
        \psline(-1,-1)(0,-1)
        \psline(0,1)(1,1)
        \psdots[dotstyle=Bo](-1,-1)
        \psdots(0,1)
    \end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: you should accept answers if it is ok. Otherwise it will be left as unanwered ...